# Slack-Overflow - A programmer's best friend, now in Slack

Tags: app, python

A quick hack made in a couple of hours.

A programmer's best friend, now in Slack. Search StackOverflow right from Slack without coming off as dumb.

[image]

Setup is super simple and straightforward.

https://github.com/karan/slack-overflow

Comment: does this still work? how can I add it to my slack?